# MYSQL Created_tmp_disk_tables value increases on almost every query

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning

Should I be concerned that tmp_disk_table # is growing even when I run a simple query like elect id from table with 1000 rows where id is an integer and is primary key)

I've fiddled with other settings (bumped max_tmp_table memory,max_heap_table_size, etc. bumping them from 128mb to 1 gb etc.) but that number of tmp_disk_tables keeps growing

This doesn't seem right to me but a DBA at my company says it's normal. 
Here is what I am using to check that number:

We are running MYSQL 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 on a lunix server:

> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'created_tmp%tables';

Variable_name, Value
'Created_tmp_disk_tables', '1524870'
'Created_tmp_tables', '23686492'

```
CREATE TABLE mdl_course (
    id bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    category bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    - other columns removed for formatting issues -
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY mdl_cour_cat_ix (category) USING BTREE, 
    KEY mdl_cour_idn_ix (idnumber) USING BTREE, 
    KEY mdl_cour_sho_ix (shortname) USING BTREE, 
    KEY mdl_cour_sor_ix (sortorder)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2916
          DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
          COMMENT='Central course table'
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! Could you provide the `EXPLAIN` and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE\G` output?

Comment: I am having trouble with the format for the create table but here is an explain for a simple query that increases created_tmp_disk_tables counter:     id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'mdl_course', 'const', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'const', '1', 'Using index'

Comment: the query is a select id on this table where id =1... that's it... CREATE TABLE `mdl_course` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   - other columns removed for formatting issues - 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_cat_ix` (`category`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `mdl_cour_idn_ix` (`idnumber`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `mdl_cour_sho_ix` (`shortname`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `mdl_cour_sor_ix` (`sortorder`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2916 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Central course table'

Comment: We _must_ see the `SELECT` to explain what is going on.

Comment: selkect id from mdl_course where id =1